# ElasticSearch search relevancy

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have this 3 documents:

- Marvel Sticker for Iphone 13
- Marvel Sticker for Iphone 13 Pro
- Marvel Sticker for Iphone 13 Pro Max

If I search "Iphone 13" y need to get only the first one instead of the 3 records, How can I achieve that?

looking on search relevancy doc

Comment: Unless you inform the complete term using Term Query, you will always have 3 results returned because there is correspondence with the 3 documents. elasticsearch returns the most relevant at the top of the results.